# I want my Indicator to be shown in 5 min only in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I want my Indicator to be shown in 5 min timeframe only in pine script ?

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Find out if it is the 5 min timeframe like so:

```
is_five_min = (timeframe.isminutes) and (timeframe.multiplier == 5)
```

Then put your whole code in an if check like:

```
if (is_five_min)
    // Do stuff
```

**Note:** Not all functions can work in a local scope so you might need to do something like this:

```
plot(is_five_min ? close : na)
```